# How to solve 'error: ‘geometric_shapes_msgs’ does not name a type'?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [tabletop_object_perception](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tabletop_object_perception).

I use ROS electric and run:

```
  svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/tabletop_object_perception/branches/0.4-branch/
  svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/motion_planning_common/trunk/geometric_shapes_msgs
  cd geometric_shapes_msgs/
  rosmake
  cd ..
  cd 0.4-branch/
  cd tabletop_object_detector/
```

When I rosmake,it shows:

```
  sam@/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector$ rosmake
  [ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['tabletop_object_detector']                 
  [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['tabletop_object_detector']                         
  [ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120828-193717    
  [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['tabletop_object_detector'] to:
  ['tabletop_object_detector']  
  [ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages tabletop_object_detector.  This may take a few seconds.
  [ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages                      
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                               
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
   No Makefile in package rosbuild
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                             
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common                    
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                 
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib                            
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                                 
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                          
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                                
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
   No Makefile in package roslang
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                            
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                               
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                               
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime                          
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits              
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                             
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                                   
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp                        
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs                        
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                          
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                               
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole                    
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                               
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]                                               
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean                        
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                              
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs              
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster                      
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                 
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp                            
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                  
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy                              
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                                 
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout                            
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                                
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit                          
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph                        
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam                        
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                                 
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                            
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]                                              
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosnode [ make ]                                                
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
   No Makefile in package roslaunch
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosnode ROS_NOBUILD in package rosnode                          
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> eigen [ make ]                                                  
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< eigen ROS_NOBUILD in package eigen                              
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> cminpack [ make ]                                               
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                                
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< cminpack ROS_NOBUILD in package cminpack                        
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest                          
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> flann [ make ]                                                  
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< flann ROS_NOBUILD in package flann                              
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                              
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]                                            
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                                        
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters          
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib                      
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package topic_tools                  
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                                   
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                                
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                                 
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag                            
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                                 
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                            
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbagmigration [ make ]                                        
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> actionlib_msgs [ make ]                                         
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmsg [ make ]                                                 
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                                
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                          
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbagmigration ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbagmigration
   No Makefile in package rosbagmigration
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmsg
   No Makefile in package rosmsg
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                                
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< actionlib_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package actionlib_msgs            
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostopic [ make ]                                               
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                          
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                          
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs              
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostopic ROS_NOBUILD in package rostopic                        
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> trajectory_msgs [ make ]                                        
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                            
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> visualization_msgs [ make ]                                     
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                             
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< visualization_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package visualization_msgs    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosservice ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice                    
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> geometric_shapes_msgs [ make ]                                  
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs                  
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                                 
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]                                                    
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< trajectory_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package trajectory_msgs          
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roswtf ROS_NOBUILD in package roswtf                            
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< pcl ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl                                  
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools  
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                                     
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                                    
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                                    
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure  
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> arm_navigation_msgs [ make ]                                    
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< arm_navigation_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package arm_navigation_msgs  
  [rosmake-3] Starting >>> distance_field [ make ]                                         
  [rosmake-3] Finished <<< distance_field ROS_NOBUILD in package distance_field            
  [rosmake-0] Starting >>> household_objects_database_msgs [ make ]                        
  [rosmake-1] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]                                                
  [rosmake-0] Finished <<< household_objects_database_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package household_objects_database_msgs
  [rosmake-1] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros                          
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< geometric_shapes_msgs [PASS] [ 0.86 seconds ]                   
  [rosmake-2] Starting >>> tabletop_object_detector [ make ]                               
  [ rosmake ] Last 40 linesbletop_object_detector: 39.7 sec ]   [ 1 Active 55/56 Complete ]
  {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    Scanning dependencies of target marker_generator
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    [ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/marker_generator.dir/src/marker_generator.o
    Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libmarker_generator.so
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    [ 75%] Built target marker_generator
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    Scanning dependencies of target ping_segment_object_in_hand
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    [ 77%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ping_segment_object_in_hand.dir/src/ping_segment_object_in_hand.o
    Linking CXX executable ../bin/ping_segment_object_in_hand
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    [ 77%] Built target ping_segment_object_in_hand
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    Scanning dependencies of target ping_tabletop_node
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    [ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ping_tabletop_node.dir/src/ping_tabletop_node.o
    Linking CXX executable ../bin/ping_tabletop_node
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    [ 80%] Built target ping_tabletop_node
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    Scanning dependencies of target publish_database_object
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    [ 82%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/publish_database_object.dir/src/publish_database_object.o
    /home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/src/publish_database_object.cpp:43:47: error: ‘geometric_shapes_msgs’ does not name a type
    /home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/src/publish_database_object.cpp:43:76: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
    /home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/src/publish_database_object.cpp:43:76: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
    /home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/src/publish_database_object.cpp:43:76: error: expected initializer before ‘&’ token
    make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/publish_database_object.dir/src/publish_database_object.o] Error 1
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/publish_database_object.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector/build'
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
  [ rosmake ] Output from build of package tabletop_object_detector written to:
  [ rosmake ]    /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120828-193717/tabletop_object_detector/build_output.log
  [rosmake-2] Finished <<< tabletop_object_detector [FAIL] [ 39.80 seconds ]               
  [ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package tabletop_object_detector. 
  [ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
  [ rosmake ] Results:                                                                     
  [ rosmake ] Built 56 packages with 1 failures.                                           
  [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                  
  [ rosmake ] /home/sam/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120828-193717                        
  
  sam@/home/sam/code/ros/recognition/0.4-branch/tabletop_object_detector$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42462/how-to-solve-%27error:-%E2%80%98geometric_shapes_msgs%E2%80%99-does-not-name-a-type%27-?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do not check out the packages from repositories but install from debian packages. Then you shouldn't need to compile anything but your own code.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-pr2-object-manipulation
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0